# How can I save user settings on a per user basis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, application-settings

I'm working on a program that needs a feature that has similar functionality as a contact list. I need to have user settings, but I don't know how, if it's even possible, to create application settings in code.

I would like to be able to add as many new "contact" settings as needed, so I figured if I couldn't create new settings, I should just have one setting that is a list, but that also doesn't seem to be possible. I've looked around on here and Google and can't find anything to fit my needs.

Requirements:
Store contact-like data such as phone numbers, email addresses, etc.
Be able to add as many of these contact settings as needed.
Everything in one executable file.

Edit: So there's the object data type, which seems to fit my needs. Is there a reason this wasn't an answer to any of the very similar questions to mine? It seems to be perfect..

Edit: Nevermind, seems to be compiler errors when trying to access a property of my object because it doesn't have that property until it's an instance of my own objects...

Comment: Did you consider XML? Construct a c# object that reflect your needs and serialize it

Comment: @Tigran, Will an embedded resource make the application a lot bigger?

Comment: If I store info as a string, how long can the string be?

Comment: @walkerneo: it's  not a resource, it's a database , but "standalone", without a need of installation of anything. For example: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: Sorry, I meant embedded database, not resource. The download was about 2gb, will it make the application that big?

Comment: I think you're downloading something else:) recheck, it's a very small.

Comment: @Walkerneo: This link, imo, what you need: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki , sorry but there is a confusion of different domains for Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JayP. Sql Server Compact might also be a possibility, it creates a local 'mini' database, without the need of a sql server installation.

Comment: Will the mini-database make the application much bigger?

Comment: It will make it bigger, however a database seems one of the most logical choices. A database is used for storing data like contact information.

Answer (score 1):

While it is pedantic, I'm not sure a contact list should really be considered as 'settings'. It's really data. As such, it might be better to store this data in an XML file or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my 2 coins. The data the @Walkerneo is talking about is not "settings" data. It's real data that should be considered in other way. I would suggest to separate them into 2 parts: real data and real settings.

1. The best place for real data is DB. It may be Firebird or MS SQL Compact or something else.
2. As for settings the Registry is a good place. At least Qt that is cross platform language uses this approach for Win apps

.